# Chinese Remainder Theorem Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that:

x ≡ 6(mod 9)
x ≡ 5(mod 7)
x ≡ 12(mod 10)

Has a unique solution modulo 630.

Step 1:

GCF(9,7) = 1
GCF(9,10) = 1
GCF (7,10) = 1

Step 2:

9 x 7 x 10
= 630

Step 3:

c1 = 630/9 = 70
c2 = 630 / 7 = 80
c3 = 630/10 = 63

But how exactly am I supposed to go about proving theres a unique solution modulo 630?

Comment: Do you only need to show that there exists a unique solution mod $630$, or do you also need to compute the solution?

Answer (score 1):

$$x \equiv 6 \pmod 9$$

$$x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$$
$$x \equiv 12 \pmod{ 10}$$

$$M=630$$

$$M_1=70$$

$$M_2=90$$

$$M_3=63$$

And now we find the solutions of :

$$70 x \equiv 6 \pmod 9$$

$$90 x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$$

$$63x \equiv 12 \pmod{10}$$

$$70 x \equiv 6 \pmod 9 \Rightarrow 7x \equiv 6 \pmod{9} \Rightarrow \xi_1=6$$

$$90 x \equiv 5 \pmod 7 \Rightarrow 6x \equiv 5 \pmod 7 \Rightarrow \xi_2=2$$

$$63x \equiv 12 \pmod{10}  \Rightarrow 3x \equiv 12 \pmod{10} \Rightarrow \xi_3=4$$

Therefore:

$$a_0=M_1 \xi_1+M_2 \xi_2+M_3 \xi_3=852$$

is the unique solution $\pmod {630}$

So,the general solution of the system is:

$$a \equiv 852 \pmod{630} \Rightarrow a \equiv 222 \pmod{630}$$

so, $a=222+630k,k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Where did you get the $756$?

Comment: I edited my post!!

Comment: That makes sense. So the unique solution mod 630 is 852 mod(630). I was on the right track.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which, as stated, requires only to prove that there exists a unique solution, not to compute some specific solution. That the solution is unique requires *proof*. If you are invoking some theorem then you should refer to a statement of the theorem you use (there are many variations of CRT).

Answer (score 1):

Given two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$, what can be said about the difference between them $n = x_1 - x_2$?

Well, for one thing, n must be divisible by 7... and by 9... and by 10.

What's that tell us about n?

Comment: So would the solution be x=70mod(630) and so on?

Comment: @user166971: This answer is not about finding a solution $x$, it's about proving uniqueness of a solution.

Comment: There's a subtle distinction here: showing that there is only one solution is quite different from finding that solution.  This question as far as I can see wants you to do the first.  evinda's solution, above, does the second.  I'm pointing you in the direction of the first: if there's only one solution mod 630, then for all possible pairs of solutions in Z, their difference will be a multiple of 630.